# Need for some advice to get started in retrosheets.(Baseball data for MLB)

Tags: mysql, r, windows, bash, data-science

I'm trying to understand how to use the event files (play by play data) from retrosheet. I also want to understand how to use the DiamondWare Tools provided by retrosheet before jumping the Chadwick Tools. I'm following the http://www.retrosheet.org/stepex.txt but I think this information is obsolete(maybe I'm wrong), since it uses "1982al.zip" and I don't find this data format in the web-page.

I also saw some tools have been developed in Python and R. I tryed to use tha R-package "retrosheet" (https://github.com/rmscriven/retrosheet) but it did not work very well (maybe because of my ignorance).

What I want is to learn, so my question is: Could anyone reccomend me a "tutorial" or a "guide", or give me some advices to get started to use retrosheet? What is the faster and best way to get started with retrosheet?

Thank you very much in advances.

Sergio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The retrosheet package](https://baseballwithr.wordpress.com/2015/11/25/the-retrosheet-package/) and [Retrosheet Package, Part 2](https://baseballwithr.wordpress.com/2015/11/30/retrosheet-package-part-2/) posts by the [Exploring Baseball Data with R](https://baseballwithr.wordpress.com/) blog walk the reader through a few use cases of the [`retrosheet`](https://github.com/rmscriven/retrosheet#retrosheet) [r](/questions/tagged/r) package.

The former looks at the Kansas City's Royals 2014-2015 schedule and the latter explores Mike Trout's 2013 home runs.

**Update**

It looks like `retrosheet` is not being maintained anymore. If you would like to use it, I wouldn't recommend installing it from CRAN. Rather, you should use the pull request version - [keberwein/retrosheet](https://github.com/keberwein/retrosheet) - which fixes the `getRetrosheet()` function.

To do so, follow the code below:

```
# assuming you've already installed retrosheet
# remove unmaintained version of retrosheet
remove.packages( pkgs = "retrosheet" )

# install devtools to enable you to download packages from GitHub
install.packages( pkgs = "devtools" )
library( devtools )

# install PR request version of retrosheet
install_github( repo = "keberwein/retrosheet" )

# load retrosheet
library( retrosheet )

# download 2017 MLB rosters
roster.2017 <- getRetrosheet( type = "roster", year = 2017)

# check the dimension of each data frame in roster.2017
lapply( X = roster.2017, FUN = dim )
# $ARI
# [1] 45  7
# 
# $ATL
# [1] 49  7
# 
# $BAL
# [1] 50  7
# 
# $BOS
# [1] 49  7
# 
# $CHA
# [1] 51  7
# 
# $CHN
# [1] 47  7
# 
# $CIN
# [1] 47  7
# 
# $CLE
# [1] 41  7
# 
# $COL
# [1] 41  7
# 
# $DET
# [1] 49  7
# 
# $HOU
# [1] 46  7
# 
# $KCA
# [1] 49  7
# 
# $LAN
# [1] 52  7
# 
# $MIA
# [1] 43  7
# 
# $MIL
# [1] 50  7
# 
# $MIN
# [1] 52  7
# 
# $NYA
# [1] 51  7
# 
# $NYN
# [1] 52  7
# 
# $OAK
# [1] 54  7
# 
# $PHI
# [1] 51  7
# 
# $PIT
# [1] 47  7
# 
# $SDN
# [1] 52  7
# 
# $SEA
# [1] 61  7
# 
# $SFN
# [1] 49  7
# 
# $SLN
# [1] 48  7
# 
# $TBA
# [1] 53  7
# 
# $TEX
# [1] 51  7
# 
# $TOR
# [1] 60  7
# 
# $WAS
# [1] 49  7

# end of script #
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I saw and tried to use these blogs.  I found a problem related with the first example of [The retrosheet 
 package](https://baseballwithr.wordpress.com/2015/11/25/the-retrosheet-package/.) The function: "getRetrosheet()" is not updated. I looked for help and the only post I found was this [question-answer](https://github.com/rmscriven/retrosheet/issues/5). The date of this link is from one year ago and nobody has updated the function, so I thought that probably nobody is working on keeping updated the package. Lot of thanks again.

Comment: @SergioMarreroMarrero no problem. I didn't realize this package was not being maintained. However, I did see that someone issued a [pull request](https://help.github.com/articles/about-pull-requests/) on GitHub that fixes the `getRetrosheet()` function. I've updated my answer on how you would delete the old `retrosheet` package and install the pull request version. I hope you also checkout the [`Lahman`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Lahman/Lahman.pdf) package, it offers player data from 1871 to 2015.

Comment: Lot of thanks again for your fast answer and your effort on update your answer and explain how to make the pull with the fixed function. I know the Lahman database, but I need play-by-play data for the model I'm developing. Thank you very much again.

Sergio.

Comment: Ah I see. Good luck with your model!

Comment: Sorry for keep bothering you, but I am really frustrated. I'm trying to begin with [step-by-step](http://www.retrosheet.org/stepex.txt)  guide that [retrosheet](http://www.retrosheet.org/game.htm) provides for users to get started. I am pretty sure the guide is deprecated. I tried to do the first example and it doesn't work. I don't know where or who I can ask to. Do you know something about this issue? It seems very weird to me, as there should be more people doing themselves the same question but I don't find anything more. Thanks again and sorry for asking.

Comment: Hey @SergioMarreroMarrero I just glanced at the guide and it looks like this isn't an [tag:r] question but a [tag:dos] question. I know it doesn't help, but frustration is a part of the game. Wish I could help more but just keep trying!

Comment: Hi again @aspiringurbandatascientist ! Lot of thanks anyway. It helps to lift the mood ! I'll keep trying to look for help using "dos" tag. Bye !

Comment: This is fascinating...some of the `type` values in `getRetrosheet()` work; while the 'schedule' value returns this strange error message. I'll explore under the hood to see if I can simply pull the 2017 schedule.